# How to monitor progress of iPhone sync operation on Catalina

Tags: iphone, finder, data-synchronization, console

I am currently trying to sync about 10,000 photos to my iPhone. I am suspicious that the sync process is stuck somehow, though. It is two hours in and I cannot see any sign of progress being made.

Catalina moved iPhone sync to the Finder and removed information about how many photos have been synced; all you see is a pie chart in the sidebar next to the device name.

Is there a way I can monitor the progress of the sync operation using Console.app or the command line? Does the sync process publish log messages anywhere? I want to verify that it is actually making progress on the sync operation.